# Doubly LinkedList in Java

Tags: java, nodes, doubly-linked-list

So I have to implement some methods for a doubly Linked List...my main question is how to implement a remove At Index method and a reverse String method.

I already have a node class. The remove At Index method gets an index (of type int) and removes the element at that index. The reverse String method returns a String that contains all of the elements in the list in the reverse order...

I made a contains method I just don't know how to use it to fix these problems or if I need to use it to fix the problems...
Please help!

Comment: What have you tried? We can't really help you without seeing any of your doubly linked list's code. Edit your post and add some code!

Comment: OK, for removeAt, there are basically three cases you'll have to consider separately.  Either you wish to remove the first element of the list, or the last element, or an element in between.  You'll also want to consider the case where the index does not correspond to something in the list.  Work out first exactly what you'll need to change, for each of those cases.  Then try to turn it into code.  For reverse String - please clarify - are the nodes in the list characters?